# What are the dangers of buying a windows entreprise key online?

Tags: security, windows-10, best-practices, activation

For multiple reasons I've settled on using Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

Apart of getting a fake key or getting a legitimate key revoked, what are the dangers of purchasing / applying an unknown product key to your windows system ?

Edit:
I'm willing to take the risk of getting a non-working cd key, on the other hand I'm afraid of having my system compromised by a malicious vendor. Do they have any sort of control on your system via the license / key ?

Comment: Unless you're buying from a reputable vendor, surely the possibility (likelihood!) of getting a fake one is enough?

Comment: Another viewpoint, but stress on the reputable or trusted vendor. Just find a good vendor, and this shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: If you have to ask then you probably shouldn't be purchasing it from the vendor in question. It isn't hard to purchase a product key from a reputable vendor.

Comment: I'm willing to take the risk of getting a non-working cd key, on the other hand I'm afraid of having my system compromised by a malicious vendor. Do they have any sort of control on your system via the license / key ?

Comment: It's not "non-working" that I'd be concerned about. It's the Business Software Alliance raiding you I'd be concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged this question [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices). Best practice is to buy from a reputable vendor so that you do not have to worry about getting a fake key or anything else.